# Proof that $\sigma$-algebras are uncountable

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

This is exercise $1.3$ in Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications*. I'd like this proofread please. The theorem is out there on math.se but I'd like this particular proof checked, kthx

Theorem: If $\mathcal M$ is an infinite $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, $\mathcal M$ has cardinality at least that of the continuum.

Proof:

1) I proved that $X$ is infinite

2) $X, \varnothing \in \mathcal M$ so I can define a sequence using the axiom of choice:

$F_1 = \varnothing, F_2 = X$,

$F_3 = \text{ any set in } \mathcal M \setminus \left \{ { \varnothing, X } \right \}; \ldots ;F_n = \text{ any set in } \mathcal M \setminus \left \{ {F_1, F_2, \ldots, F_{n-1} } \right \}$

I prove there are a countably infinite number of disjoint sets in this construction.

3) Any indexed family $\langle F_i \rangle$ so constructed is a set of measurable sets, the disjoint union of which is also measurable.

Each family such constructed corresponds to an mapping $\iota: \mathbb N \hookrightarrow \bigsqcup_{i \mathop \in \mathbb N} F_i$, by the definition of an indexed family.

I prove that each $\iota$ is an injection, using the disjointness of the sets in $\langle F \rangle$.

4) $\displaystyle \iota^\to : \mathcal P (\mathbb N) \hookrightarrow \mathcal P \left({ \bigsqcup_{i \mathop \in \mathbb N} F_i}\right)$

The induced map is an injection because an injection induces an injection on the power sets.

***MISTAKE FOUND HERE*** in Umberto's answer

$\mathcal P \left({ \bigsqcup_{i \mathop \in \mathbb N} F_i}\right)$ is a set of measurable sets in $\mathcal M$ so $\mathcal P \left({ \bigsqcup_{i \mathop \in \mathbb N} F_i}\right) \subseteq \mathcal M$

5) Show there is an injection from $\mathbb R \hookrightarrow \mathcal M$ using $\mathcal P (\mathbb N) \sim \mathbb R$

$\blacksquare$?

Comment: This disjoint union is not a subset of X, so in what sense is it measurable?

Comment: It is a disjoint union of sets picked from $\mathcal M$ using choice

Comment: that doesn’t really answer my question, or at least I don’t see how it does. The disjoint union is not an element of the sigma algebra, so in what sense is it measurable?

Comment: Yes it is? every set in $\mathcal M$ is a subset of $X$, and $\mathcal M$ is closed under countable union

Comment: Countable union, sure. But what about disjoint union? How do you know that there even is such a disjoint family of measurable sets? For instance, if $F_1 = X$, then no other nonempty $F_2\in\mathcal M$ can be disjoint from $F_1$. It seems that some care must be taken.

Comment: @AOrtiz I constructed $F_1 = \varnothing$, $F_2 = X$, and I proved $X$ is infinite. Part of the proof is constructing such a family, I didn't put all the details here, that's why I wrote "I prove there are a countably infinite number of disjoint sets in this construction". Closure under countable union and closure under countable disjoint union are equivalent, see https://tinyurl.com/y8mdfrfv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78330/discussion-between-gfauxpas-and-aortiz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping looks off. In particular, $\mathcal P(\bigsqcup_{i \in \mathbb N} F_i) \subseteq \cal M$ can't be right.

How about defining $\iota : \mathcal P(\mathbb N) \to \mathcal M$ by $$\iota(S) = \bigsqcup_{i \in S} F_i$$
and showing $\iota$ is an injection. This gives you what you need.

Comment: aaaah, I *was* suspicious of that part. Thanks!